# What is the maximum allowed intensity for light beams pointing at the sky for non-aviation purposes?

Tags: regulations, hkcad

In Hong Kong, I'm designing a show with light beams and i'm thinking using Robe Megapointe lights (https://www.robe.cz/megapointe/). I've been ask by the client to follow the aviation regulation. Though the aviation regulation doesn't give any figure, only subjective indications, and I have no idea if my lights are acceptable or too strong.

The website of Robe announces: 2.200.000 lx @ 5 m and 137.500 lx @ 20 m. I'm trying to find similar regulation references in other countries to make up my mind.

Any of you have seen any figures in that domain?

Comment: I retagged the question to [tag:regulations], since the FAA is the aviation authority in the USA, not Hong Kong. Feel free to roll back if you specifically wish to know the FAA regulations only.

Answer (score 2):

Article 80(1) of the [Air Navigation (Hong Kong) Order 1995](https://www.ais.gov.hk/HKAIP/aic/AIC05-10.pdf) stipulates that

> A person shall not exhibit in Hong Kong any light which —
>
> (a) by reason of its glare is liable to endanger aircraft taking off from or landing at an aerodrome; or
>
> (b) by reason of its liability to be mistaken for an aeronautical ground light is liable to endanger aircraft.
>
> Any such contravention is liable on summary conviction to a fine.

The full text of the regulation can be read [here](https://www.elegislation.gov.hk/hk/cap448C?xpid=ID_1438403209089_003).

Given this text, if your show is going to be anywhere near the approach or departure path to/from the airport (anywhere on Lantau Island, or east/west of the Gold Coast) you should probably refrain from using such lighting. I would strongly suggest you get approval from the authorities well before the event using an experienced local consultant, and prepare for that approval to be given or denied based on subjective analysis.